# Permutation on a strange string

Tags: c++, math, combinations, permutation

There is a strange string of 10 characters ether '0' or '1'. I have n filter strings each having 10 characters ether '0' or '1'. A '1' at the i-th position in a filter string means that if I applies this filter to the i-th character of the strange string, i-th character of strange string will be inverted: it becomes '1' if it was '0', and vice versa, whereas a '0' at the i-th position in a filter string will not do anything to the strange string. I can apply any number of filters. I can pick any number of filters and can apply to strange string. Now i want to find how many different subsets of all the filters can I apply to transform this strange string so that strange string will contain only 1's? I am not able to generalise the problem for any number of strings. Can anybody help.

Let us have some test cases
**Enter strange string :**
1111111111
**Total filter strings** : 
2
**Enter filter strings** :
0000000000

0000000000
**Output is:** 4
**Explanation** : Strange string is already having all characters 1's, and I have two different identity filters. I can either apply the empty subset of filters, the first filter only, the second filter only, or both.

**Enter strange string :**
0101010101
**Total filter strings** : 
 3
**Enter filter strings** :
1010101010

1010000000
0000101010
**Output is: 2

Explanation** : I can either apply the first filter (and invert all 0's) or apply the second and third filters in any order.

Comment: It's possible that none of the filters will get you to a state of all 1s, yes?

Comment: Please see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29 for the method getLevenshteinDistance. This will tell you how many bits are different between the strange string and 1111111111. And if you have n input strings, you may have to go through 2^n applications of the filters consisting of the power set. For example, suppose you have 3 filter strings, a, b, and c. You would have to apply 2^3 filters: null, a, b, c, ab, ac, bc, abc. Take two aspirin and ping me later.

Comment: And what's your specific problem? You don't know how to code the permutations? Or you need to prove that the operation of applying the filters does not depend on the order of the application of the filters, such that you need only permutations of sets of filters?

Comment: Think about what happens when you apply a filter to the original string. Now you have a new string and 1 less filter to worry about. Use recursion to reduce the problem down until you can handle it easily.

Comment: @rajah9 Yes, it is possible.

Comment: There is no need to use levenshtein distance. That just over complicates things. I can think of an algorithm that is O(n^2) and not O(2^n) if I understand the problem correctly.

Comment: @Kevin O(n^2) solution will be acceptable. I was thinking of XOR kind of thing.

Comment: @rajah9 Let us suppose n is 100000. Then what?

Comment: I think, and you'd have to do 2 ^ 100000 computations. BTW, I agree with others that the Levenshtein distance would be overkill.

Comment: This problem has remarkable similarities with [this ongoing contest problem](https://www.codechef.com/DEC15/problems/CHEFFILT) with N limit 100000

Answer (score 0):

Brute force algorithm:

```
std::uint16_t apply_filters(std::uint16_t init,
                            const std::vector<std::uint16_t>& filters,
                            const std::vector<bool>& mask)
{
    auto res = init;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != filters.size(); ++i) {
        if (mask[i]) {
            res ^= filters[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}

bool increase(std::vector<bool>& bs)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != bs.size(); ++i) {
        bs[i] = !bs[i];
        if (bs[i] == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; // overflow
}


std::size_t count_filters_combination(std::uint16_t init,
                                      const std::vector<std::uint16_t>& filters)
{
    std::vector<bool> bs(filters.size());

    std::size_t count = 0;
    const std::uint16_t expected = 0b1111111111;
    do
    {
        if (expected == apply_filters(init, filters, bs)) {
            ++count;
        }
    } while (increase(bs));
    return count;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/TabjNq)

Comment: Dude, the guy's already done your homework for you. Open up a debugger and trace through it.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. Can u provide me some efficient method so that I can even process 10^5 strings without Time Limit Exceed.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my solution in python. It should be pretty easy to understand. I'll leave it to you to translate it to C++.

```
def filterCombinations(original, filters):
    combinations = 1 if original == 0b1111111111 else 0
    for i in xrange(len(filters)):
        newvalue = original ^ filters[i]
        newfilters = filters[i+1:]
        combinations += filterCombinations(newvalue, newfilters)
    return combinations
```

Using 3 filters, the first level of recursion looks like this:

```
filterCombinations(S, [F1, F2, F3])
--> X +
    filterCombinations(S^F1, [F2, F3]) +
    filterCombinations(S^F2, [F3]) +
    filterCombinations(S^F3, [])
```

Where `X` is 1 if `S == 1111111111` and `0` otherwise.

Comment: How can I make it faster ?

Comment: You might be able to speed things up by caching results. Do a lookup before doing any recursion. The cache will probably get pretty large though so I'm not sure how feasible it is.